# Observable private property in Mobx

Tags: observable, private, mobx

I have a problem with observable private property in the Mobx store. The thing is that observable private property with getter and setter doesn't work, while a public observable property works perfectly fine. Why is so? I tested both private and public property (`#privateSelectedType` and `selectedType`) interchangeably to do the same thing.

**EDIT2**: I've created a codesandbox to better show the case: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pond-kglzr?file=/src/carsStore.js

Here is a code that exemplifies the situation. I use this store to display all types and mark the `selectedType`:

```javascript
class CarsStore {
  #types = ["defaultType", "type1", "type2"];
  #privateSelectedType = "defaultType";
  selectedType = "defaultType";

  otherThings = [];

  get types() {
    return this.#types;
  }

  get privateSelectedType() {
    return this.#privateSelectedType;
  }

  set privateSelectedType(selectedType) {
    this.#privateSelectedType = selectedType;
    // call function updating otherThings, that's why I want to use setter in this store
    this.#updateOtherThings();
  }

  #updateOtherThings = () => {
    //update otherThings
  }
}

decorate(CarsStore, {
  "#types": observable,
  "#privateSelectedType": observable,
  selectedType: observable,
  otherThings: observable
});
```

**EDIT**: Simply changing all occurrences of `#privateSelectedType` to public field `_publicSelectedType` makes this code working. It seems to me that mobx simply doesn't work or works differently with JavaScript private fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER:**

After some research and debugging of your code in the comments, it turns out that mobx internally is trying to decorate the prototype properties of CarsStore, where private fields are **missing**:

[image]

The reason for this is that in this proposal syntax **private fields are only visible and reachable from the body of the class**, because they are recorded as a metadata and are accessible only from the engine. More info in this [link(point 5)](https://2ality.com/2019/07/private-class-fields.html). I hope this answers your question now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case.  When I turn to the private field with getter and setter it stops working whether it's computed or not.

Comment: Can you write down the exact code which is not working?

Comment: I have created a sandbox example of the code. In carsStore file, if you change all occurrences of #selectedTypeName for something public it starts working. https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pond-kglzr?file=/src/carsStore.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation that is documented by MobX.  Fortunately there is a workaround syntax:

https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations

I've used it many times and it works just fine.